Showing that homomorphism is uniquely determined by its image on $X$
Let $H$ and $G$ be groups and let $X ⊆ G$ such that $\left<X\right> = G$. Show that a homomorphism $G → H$ is
uniquely determined by its image on $X$: that is, if $ϕ : G → H$ and $ψ : G → H$ are homomorphisms
such that $ϕ(x) = ψ(x)$ for all $x ∈ X$, then $ϕ(g) = ψ(g)$ for all $g ∈ G$.
My thought process goes as follows: Given that $\left<X\right> = G$, every element $g \in G$ can be expressed as a product of elements in $X$. That is, for any $g \in G$, there exist $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n \in X$ such that $g = x_1x_2\ldots x_n$.
Now, let's consider two homomorphisms $\phi$ and $\psi$ from $G$ to $H$ such that $\phi(x) = \psi(x)$ for all $x \in X$. We want to show that $\phi(g) = \psi(g)$ for all $g \in G$.
Since $\phi$ and $\psi$ are homomorphisms, they preserve the group operation. Thus, for any $g = x_1x_2\ldots x_n \in G$, we have: $$\phi(g)=\phi(x_1x_2\ldots x_n)=\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)\ldots\phi(x_n)$$ $$ψ(g)=ψ(x_1​x_2​…x_n​)=ψ(x_1​)ψ(x_2​)…ψ(x_n​)$$
I don't know what I do next at this point.

Well, your proof is complete, provided you begin with replacing $X$ by $X\cup X^{-1}$. I.e. if $G$ is generated by $X$ then an element of $G$ is a product of $x_i^{\pm1},x_i\in X$. And $\phi(x_i^{-1})=\phi(x_i)^{-1}$ and same for $\psi$.

The terminology is wrong: "image on $X$" should read "restriction to $X$". ("Image on $X$" doesn't have a standard meaning.)

Here's a MathJax tutorial :)

@AnneBauval Thanks, quick question, why are we denoting product of elements of $X$ and their inverses as union? Shouln't it be intersection because of "and"?

By "elements of $X$ and their inverses" I meant: "elements of $X$ and inverses of elements of $X$", i.e. elements of $X$ and elements of $X^{-1}$", i.e. "elements of $X\cup X^{-1}$".

I came back to this question now, why is it a union though? excuse my poor intuition on set theory

As mentioned in the comments, it's not necessary true that every element is a product of elements of $X$, but a product of elements of $X$ and their inverses. Note that for each $x\in X$ we have $\phi(x^{-1})=(\phi(x))^{-1}=(\psi(x))^{-1}=\psi(x^{-1})$, and so the two maps coincide on the inverses as well. And then, if $g=x_1x_2...x_n$ is a product of elements of $X$ and their inverses then:
$\phi(g)=\phi(x_1)\phi(x_2)...\phi(x_n)=\psi(x_1)\psi(x_2)...\psi(x_n)=\psi(g),$
and we are done.
Here is another proof that I like, which doesn't make us think how the elements of $\langle X\rangle$ look like. Define:
$K=\{g\in G: \phi(g)=\psi(g)\}$
It is very easy to check that $K$ is a subgroup of $G$. By assumption it contains $X$, and since $G=\langle X\rangle$ is by definition the smallest subgroup that contains $X$, we must have $K=G$.

The question was a duplicate.
